# bootstrap tabscollapse duplicate form element id issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap tabcollapse, it automatically load accordian content while window has desktop size. In a result we have a conflict of duplicate element form id.

any suggestion for this?

Thanks